# Mercurial: multiline commit message on the command line?

Tags: command-line, mercurial

How can I specify a multiline commit message for mercurial on the command line?

```
hg commit -m "* add foo\n* fix bar"
```

does not work.  The log shows:

```
changeset:   13:f2c6526e5911
tag:         tip
date:        Fri Jan 23 23:22:36 2009 +0100
files:       foobar.cpp
description:
    * add foo\n*fix bar
```

Comment: I guess this has to be solved through the command shell itself. If your command shell can give you a way to supply some multi-line text as a single parameter (maybe by having a '\' at the end of the line), then HG shold have no problem with it...

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right.  However, this is the only usecase for me personally, where I would use it on a regular basis, that's why I didn't ask it as a bash-question.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

> Mercurial: multiline commit message on
>   the command line?

Hit enter.

```
$ hg commit -m "Did some work
> Now I'm done"
```

One of the things is that only the first line shows up in hg log:

```
$ hg log
changeset:   0:d2dc019450a2
tag:         tip
user:        Aaron Maenpaa <zacherates@gmail.com>
date:        Sat Jan 24 07:46:23 2009 -0500
summary:     Did some work
```

... but if you fire up "hg view" you can see that the whole message is there.

Edited to add:

... but hg -v log shows the whole message:

```
$ hg -v log
changeset:   0:d2dc019450a2
tag:         tip
user:        Aaron Maenpaa <zacherates@gmail.com>
date:        Sat Jan 24 07:46:23 2009 -0500
files:       work
description:
Did some work
Now I'm done
```

Comment: The "Enter" behavior is dependant on UNIX-like shells. Is there a way to do it with Windows CMD?

Comment: @Hosam Other than installing cygwin (or mingwin) and using bash I can't think of anything.

Comment: @Hosam Aly: Can you use \n or \r\n or \r? I'm not sure if the shellexpands it, but Mercurial might.

Comment: @person-b: The shell does not expand it AFAIK, and I don't have Mercurial to check it. But @Jason has a good answer below.

Comment: Thanks! `hg help log` doesn't have the `v` flag (at-least not for me). Full summary is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: FYI: Even all *NIX shells won't work.  My fav, 'tcsh', gives "Unmatched '."  I temporarily switch to bash when I need the behavior described in the solution above.

Comment: @Justin: full help including global options is hidden behind `hg -v help log`.

Answer (score 17):

From **Windows cmd**, do this command for a multiline commit.

```
hg commit -l con
```

This allows you to enter a multiple line commit message straight from the command line.  To end your message, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and on a line by itself hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

**Why?** The `-l` option to `hg commit` says to read the commit message from a file, and `con` specifies that the file is actually the console.

Comment: Still looking find a way in the docs to do this for the "hg tag" command because `-l` is `--local` and not "--logfile" (like it is for hg commit).

Answer (score 9):

If you're doing it interactively (vs. from a script), just do `hg commit` without the -m flag. I'm not sure what the behavior is on Linux or Mac, but on Windows it pops up Notepad with a file that you fill out and save for a multiline message.

Comment: Is there some way to save and close notepad all in one keystroke? That's what annoys me about this approach.

Comment: I think there's a way (via an .ini file) to tell Mercurial to call some other application rather than Notepad, then you just need to find your favorite editor.

Comment: It uses the editor specified in the hgrc.  On Windows, it defaults to notepad if none is specified.

Comment: @DougMcClean I just go `Alt, F, S, Alt, F, X`. It's 6 key presses, but you can do it fairly fast because of the pattern. (Note that I don't mean `Alt+F, S, Alt+F, X` which seems harder to type.)

Answer (score 5):

I know, there is already a solution for linux users, but I needed another solution for windows command line, so I was looking for it...

And I found one:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2011-November/040855.html

```
hg commit -l filename.txt
```

I hope, it's useful for someone out there ,)

[EDIT]
oO - it has already been added to the help

> -l --logfile FILE        read commit message from file

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way that is more close to what you tried at first:

```
hg commit -m "$(echo -e 'foo\nbar')"
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash (since version 2.0):

```
hg commit -m $'foo\nbar'
```

(I.e. put a **dollar sign** before an opening single quote to make it parse escape sequences (like `\n)` within the string — note that it doesn't work with double quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

For **Windows** with PowerShell:

```
 hg commit --message "foo`nbar"
```