# git commit --verbose equivalent in mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial

In git, I can do "git commit --verbose" to show me a diff right there in the message editor. I don't see any option for it in mercurial. Is there a mercurial plugin to show me a diff in the message editor or anything similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: There is no `git commit --verbose` equivalent in mercurial, but it's possible to hack it in.

The edit text is hard-coded in the [mercurial source](http://selenic.com/hg/file/034e55bbf7c0/mercurial/cmdutil.py#l1773), so no plugin or configuration can directly change it.

The best you can do is to hack the ui.editor setting in your hgrc to add text into the editor directly. I made a script called hg-commit-editor:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'HG: ------------------------ >8 ------------------------' >> $1
hg diff >> $1
editor $1
exit $?
```

and then set it as my commit editor in my hgrc:

```
[ui]
editor = hg-commit-editor
```

This appends the output of "hg diff" to the bottom of the edit text file after a special line ([source](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/853001c84114/mercurial/cmdutil.py#l170)) so it's not included as part of the commit message.

Comment: Didn't see your answer at first. Good feedback building on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291826/how-do-i-customize-the-commit-message-file-generated-by-hg-commit I mentioned in my answer. +1

Comment: Yep, your answer and the links there got me started, then I pieced this info together. The only thing I don't like about this approach is if they started using ui.editor for other purposes, like launching a config editor, then this would cause problems.

Comment: I don't see an problem with your approach, being a *local* config, with a wrapper to the editor. It looks fine.

Comment: Oh, it is fine since ui.editor is only used as a commit message editor, but try e.g. running "hg-commit-editor .hg/hgrc", and notice how bizarre the behavior is. If any extensions or future versions of mercurial tried to use this editor on anything but commit message files, it would get ugly.

Comment: True. I guess, in that case, you would have to extend Mercurial in order to define a ui.commit.editor ;-)

Comment: The only problem with this is it shows diffs for all files instead of only the ones that are to be committed (and there isn't proper syntax highlighting). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This can probably be improved with the newly added `_linebelow` support so that you don't need to prefix your line with `HG:`: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/853001c84114/mercurial/cmdutil.py#l170

Answer (score 1):

Not directly but you could combine:

- <del>"[Mercurial: multiline commit message on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934532/6309)"

  `hg commit -l filename.txt`</del>
  (that would commit without opening the editor)
- "[How do I customize the 'commit message file' generated by `hg commit`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291826/how-do-i-customize-the-commit-message-file-generated-by-hg-commit)"
  Using the text you just generated as a commit message you would see when the editor comes up when you `hg commit`.
  with:
- "[In Mercurial (hg), how do you see a list of files that will be pushed if an “hg push” is issued?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041831/6309)"
  `hg -q outgoing --style ~/out-style.txt | sort -u`
  or:
  `hg outgoing -v |grep files: |cut -c 14- |tr ' ' '\n' |sort -u`

So: generating a file with the right information in it (list of files to be pushed) as the commit message.

Comment: I'm not sure that helps with what I want to do. I don't want the diff info to _be_ the commit message, I just want to see it while I'm _writing_ the commit message. "git commit --verbose" shows an editor, but includes the output of "git diff" below the line for reference. "hg commit -l" prevents any editor from being shown.

Comment: The first bullet point isn't relevant, either. "hg commit -l" can't help. I found some useful stuff in "How do I customize the 'commit message file'", though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to download [this](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/default/hgeditor) (use the `raw` link on the left hand side), put it in your `$PATH`, then set `HGEDITOR` environment variable to this script.

When doing `hg commit`, you'll see the diff in a separate window.

See also https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/hgeditor

@Mu Mind's script should still work, and probably preferable if you want it to behave as close as `git commit --verbose`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same result, but nearest iteration:

before commit you can `hg diff` to see diff in WC, using [alias extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AliasExtension) you can create alias for command-pair "hg diff & hg commit"

Comment: I don't understand... If I do "hg diff && hg commit", then the commit message editor will pop up immediately so there's no time to see the diff.